PnP SPFX dynamic form make overriden fields match OOTB fields
I'm using PnP SPFx controls dynamic form and followed this basic tutorial. I've been able to get a basic form for my SharePoint online list working.
Now I want to customize a field. I found this thread about setting up a field override and it does override the field -- but it looks awful and doesn't match all the other input fields on my form that are out of the box.
Is there a way to get the basic OOTB markup and styling and then modify it for the small changes I'm trying to create in functionality?
I found this Field Customizer Out-of-the-box Fields Controls documentation. If I'm reading that right it is supposed to help with what I'm trying to do:

These controls represent React controls that can be used in SPFx Field Customizers to provide rendering of the fields similar to out of the box experience.

But I can't seem to get that working from documentation there. Does anybody have a tutorial on using those helpers? Or some other documentation on how to do it?
